# How can I remove Microsoft Store from Task View in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store, task-view

How can I remove the "Microsoft Store" from the Task View in Windows 10 (pro)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any item in Task View that is not an actual Desktop view, you can right click on the object, right click, and remove it.

[image]